# How can I convert HL7 V2 messages to HL7 FHIR messages using GCP services?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-healthcare

I'm using GCP and I'm new to Healthcare.

I want to convert HL7 V2 messages to HL7 FHIR messages. Google shared an open source solution for this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/healthcare-data-harmonization-dataflow

But I want to be able to convert these messages one by one, as they arrive. Probably using a Cloud Function.

Is there any way I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

With some quick searching, I was able to find this documentation

- https://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/v2-to-fhir/

Comment: Interresting link but how can I use this combined with GCP. I cannot find any informations on how to use their project https://github.com/HL7/v2-to-fhir/.

Comment: GCP have several solutions than can process your needs, the easiest is Cloud Functions which requires a project created. from there you can look at 'getting started' guides for your preferred language which should have everything documented for your needs
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstarts

Comment: google has some open source utilities for v2 to fhir conversion - not sure if any are integrated into GCP services or not.  See : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/healthcare-data-harmonization    - EDIT: look under the mapping_configs folder for the conversion mappings that are possible